# Is it possible to cancel all Notification when the app is deleted?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working  on a application that reminds about the expiry date. I have implemented the same using `Uilocanotification` with repeat Interval (`NSMonthCalendarUnit`, `NSDayCalendarUnit`,`NSDayCalendarUnit`).

For example. I have set a local notification on 03/10/2012
 and if I delete the application from the iPad/iPhone. And I again Re-install the app again I still receive the old notification that was set before reinstalling. Is it possible to `cancelallNotification` when the app is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you could do a one-time only check when your app is installed and run this:

```
- (void)cancelAllLocalNotifications
```

i.e.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defaults objectForKey:@"FIRST-TIME-CHECK"] == null){
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
      [defaults setValue:@"WHATEVER" forKey:@"FIRST-TIME-CHECK"];
}
```